# Automatically fill combobox in views

Tags: views

I have created views with a node type (Property) that has term reference to vocabulary (Cities).
Vocabulary (Cities) has a terms in a hierarchical order (City-Street).

I need to do the views in which I have two combobox for vocabulary terms (City-Street) with the following behavior:

- When user select a City I would like to automatically fill the second
  combobox(Street).
- When user select City I need a list all of the
  streets for that terms. Now I have a list only when user select an
  item from combobox Street. I have tried the Hierarchical Select
  module and it didn't meet my needs.

Do I need to make my own module, and which hook or hooks to use, or is there another solution?

I hope that I was clear.

Best regards,

Goran

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Hierarchical Select](http://drupal.org/project/hierarchical_select).